# How to get string if substring match at beginning or middle, in Python's re?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
fileList = 
['notamatch','RC_test_CN_SK','test_SLU','test_CO','test_UL','SC_test_SRV']
for file in fileList:
    re.findall('\w+test\w+',file)
for file in fileList:
    re.findall('\Atest\w+',file)
```

The first for loop prints 'RC_test_CN_SK', and 'SC_test_SRV'.
The second for loop prints 'test_SLU','test_CO', and 'test_UL'.

How do I do one re.findall search and get the five files I want?

Comment: I don't see any print statements

Comment: I can't figure out what that findall thing is all about? What do you want to match? is `RE_nottest_CN_SK` in or out?

Comment: How is what you want different than just `"test" in filename`?

Comment: You may want `'(^|_)test(_|$)'` which assumes that you want to match stuff separated by _.

Comment: @PeterWood re.findall was automatically printing. You can add "print " infront of the command to make it print, if it isn't for you.

Answer (score 1):

Test if your values start with 0+ word chars from the beginning of the string and then contain `test`:

```
import re
fileList = ['notamatch','RC_test_CN_SK','test_SLU','test_CO','test_UL','SC_test_SRV']
for file in fileList:
    if re.search(r'^\w*test', file):
        print(file)
# => ['RC_test_CN_SK','test_SLU','test_CO','test_UL','SC_test_SRV']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/btBtSA)

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you @Wiktor.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform multiple searches using the regex or operator `|` in your example, you can perform the following loop:

```
for file in fileList:
    re.findall('\w+test\w+|\Atest\w+',file)
```

This query will match if either `\w+test\w+` or `\Atest\w+` is found.

Comment: That fails for me in the python shell.